# How can Click on bitmap in Espresso test?

Tags: android, testing, bitmap, android-espresso

I have `bitmap` (`R.drawable.my_image`) in my android-project, How can to testing this image by espresso test UI? I want click on this image, I write:

```
onView(withHint(R.drawable.my_image)).perform(click());
```

But this is not work :(

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't click on Bitmap. Bitmap by itself is not visible, you need a mean to render it on the screen (ImageView?).
Secondly, `R.drawable.my_image` is reference to Drawable call my_image. To reference the view use `R.id.<id_of_imageview>`.

I use this in my test and it works fine.

`onView(withId(R.id.imgPhoto)).perform(click());`

You could also use `ViewMatchers#withContentDescription` for this but I much prefer using `withId`. Both work together with `anyOf` or `allOf`.

Example
`onView(allOf(withId(R.id.imgPhoto)
                , withContentDescription("OMG")))
.check(matches(isDisplayed()));`

Comment: my_image in project draw in canvas, so my_image have not ImageView

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `R.drawable.my_image` is your resource id for the image. For this case you have to use
`onView(withId(R.drawable.my_image)).perform(click());`

For `withHint`, which is getting resource id, it is mentioned in google doc that "Returns a matcher that matches a descendant of `TextView` that is displaying the hint associated with the given resource id." I think this is not suitable for you bitmap.

More details could be found under [this](https://android-test-kit.googlecode.com/git/docs/javadocs/espresso/espresso-core-2.0-javadoc/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#withHint(int)) link:

If this not the case please let us know more details to figure out why it is not clickable.

Some basic samples could be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoStartGuide).

Comment: onView(withId(R.drawable.my_image)).perform(click()); - this is not work :(

Comment: android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: my.package:drawable/my_image.

my_image in project draw in canvas, so my_image have not ImageView

Comment: Could you please copy the full error message? It would be helpful to see the view hierarchy.